# C++ split(parse) any string type by any pattern to user-specified arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, unicode, stl

1. Is there a way to write common algorithm to parse string of user-defined type using user-defined pattern with user-provided list of arguments?
   Sample code:

   ```
   template <typename CharT, typename ...Args> 
   bool parse_string_to_args(std::basic_string<CharT> string,
                             const CharT* pattern, Args&&... args)
   {
       // for char: I'd use sscanf
       auto ret = sscanf(string.c_str(), pattern, &args...);
       if (ret == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
           return false;
       return true;
       // for wchar: swscanf ...
   }
   ```

   The sample code is, of course, awful. I want a template-based **alternative** of sscanf from C++ Standard Library if there is one...
2. If 1. is close to impossible, is there an international way to treat any characters (I know about Unicode)? Does C++11 `utf-8` or `utf-16` guarantee anything? `wchar_t` seems not to always resolve symbols, so I would prefer not to use it.

Note: it would be great if there is a cross-platform approach (basically, standard library). Linux is the highest priority.

Comment: The header `<codecvt>` offers conversion to and from `utf8` and `utf16`. Some of that can be fed to your `<locale>` to maybe fit your needs. Also the first snippet: `std::basic_stringstream` comes to mind, except that you can't use a `const CharT* pattern` with it, as C++ is trying to get away from such a type-unsafe dangerous methodology.

Comment: DeiDei, thanks. I know about the `<codecvt>`. I've also found some answers about `std::basic_stringstream` (in my case, even `istringstream`). This is closely related to the question 2. - some international type (I guess, unicode-like) would solve the issue and then I can safely use `<codecvt>` if necessary.
This is a pity in some way about the unsafeness there. It would allow more flexibility compared to `std::basic_stringstream` approach. I wonder, if there's something with regexp I can do...

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work with an arbitrary user-defined type. You need to know how at least some characters are represented in `CharT`; e.g. how do you know that a two-element `pattern` somehow represents `"%d"`, and a two-element `string` represents `"42"`? At the very least, you need a synonym for `'\0'`, since you don't pass a length for `pattern`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I expect the user knows how to correctly define pattern and string based on CharT. For instance, if `CharT=wchar_t` then `pattern=L"%lc"` - to look for single character (if this is what you meant).
Thanks for comment about '\0', I think I should consider having length of the `pattern`.

And I do **want to stay away** from knowing anything about pattern _if I can_ : just pass the data to somewhat generic alternative of sscanf and do not care - let C++ do all the work.

Comment: You didn't ask for a function that works only for `char` and `wchar_t` (that would be tractable - just dispatch to `sscanf` or `swscanf`). You asked for a function that works with sequences of arbitrary user-defined types. Say I have `struct Weird { char getChar() const; /*other members*/};` and declare that every instance of `Weird` represents the character that `getChar()` returns. Is `parse_string_to_args` expected to work on those? You need to place *some* requirements on `CharT` for the problem statement to make sense - what are those requirements? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `CharT` must be one of the following: `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` or `char32_t`.
Answering to your question about `Weird` - **No** it is not expected to work _unless_ you provide a way to treat `Weird` as one of 4 basic types above (if there is such a thing, of course)
Note: I am not 100% sure how to require that in the function (and this is actually a different question), I guess, it is related to _'type traits'_ and _static asserts_

Comment: Well, I suppose one way would be - don't make `CharT` a template parameter, but simply provide four overloads of your function, one for each of those types. Use `sscanf` for `char` and `swscanf` for `wchar_t`. For the other two, use `codecvt` facilities to convert both strings to `wchar_t` and delegate to `swscanf` once again. I can't think of anything better.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, thanks, this is definitely one of the ways to do it. Just wondered, if there is something better in 2017